# Replace meta value

Tags: php, wordpress

I searched for a while and I tried several options but I didn't find any solution. So, i have the following string that gets the status of a costum field to export to other websites.

```
<category><![CDATA[<?php listingpress_listing_status(); ?>]]></category>
```

It outputs something like this:

```
<category><![CDATA[For sale]]></category>
```

And what i need is to turn this value into a number.

**Ex:**

For sale » 100

For Rent » 110

Sold » 120

**This is the original function:**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'listingpress_listing_status' ) ) :
/**
 * Prints listing status
 *
 * @since ListingPress 1.0
 *
 * @uses listingpress_get_listing_status() To get listing status
 */
function listingpress_listing_status() {
    echo listingpress_get_listing_status( 'name' );
}
endif; // listingpress_listing_status

    if ( ! function_exists( 'listingpress_get_listing_status' ) ) :

    function listingpress_get_listing_status( $fields = 'name' ) {
        global $meta_prefix, $post;

        if ( of_get_option( 'enable_listing_status', true ) ) {
            $status = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_prefix . 'status', true );

            if ( $status == 'sold' ) {

                if ( $fields == 'name' )
                    return __( 'Sold', 'listingpress' );
                elseif ( $fields == 'slug' )
                    return 'sold';

            } elseif ( $status == 'for-sale' ) {

                if ( $fields == 'name' )
                    return __( 'For sale', 'listingpress' );
                elseif ( $fields == 'slug' )
                    return 'for-sale';

            } elseif ( $status == 'for-rent' ) {

                if ( $fields == 'name' )
                    return __( 'For rent', 'listingpress' );
                elseif ( $fields == 'slug' )
                    return 'for-rent';

            }
        } else {
            return 'no-status';
        }
    }
    endif; // listingpress_get_listing_status
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you able to edit the `listing_color()` function?

Comment: Cannot edit the function. I need to do this directly in the export php file. Thanks

Comment: Do you know whether the output from function is returned or echoed?

Comment: I understand that, if the output of `listing_color` is returned using return you can get the result stored in a variable and manipulate from there.

Comment: I put above the original function

Comment: @EMendes You posted the wrong function.

Comment: I use the the colors just as an example. I correct it now with the real values. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you can do something as mentioned below:

```
<?php
    $listing_status = '';
    if(listingpress_listing_status() == 'For sale') {
        $listing_status = 100;
    } elseif(listingpress_listing_status() == 'For rent') {
        $listing_status = 110;
    } elseif(listingpress_listing_status() == 'For rent') {
        $listing_status = 120;
    } else {
        $listing_status = listingpress_listing_status();
    }
?>
<category><![CDATA[<?php echo $listing_status; ?>]]></category>
```

A word of advice, share the problem directly with code from the beginning so that you can get help quicker.